# Ироничное "нет"

Tags: пунктуация

Не могу убедить товарища в том, что в следующих случаях запятой после *нет* не должно быть. Вот пример:

> — Что за шум? Это у меня убежало молоко?
>   — Нет у мен**я**!

Вторая реплика здесь ироничная, с восклицательной интонацией, без паузы после "нет" и с ударением только на местоимение. *Я прав, что запятая не нужна?*

Comment: Не прав. Ироничность на знаки препинания не влияет.

Comment: Римме и Третьему глазу также спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**В рамках правил** запятая после НЕТ **ставится,** так как она отсутствует только в тех случаях, когда меняется грамматическая функция слова (НЕТ в роли сказуемого или дополнения).

Но есть еще **авторская пунктуация**, в частности это касается выбора интонационного варианта при постановке запятых. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=197#pp197

Вот что Розенталь пишет об этом:

«…у Г. И. Успенского была “своя” пунктуация, не синтаксическая, которая у нас принята, а **интонационная**, показывающая **членение речи в ее живом произношении**. Писатель имел дело в процессе изложения не с мертвыми графическими знаками: он как бы слышал, он производил и изображал живую речь с ее естественными паузами».

Конечно, в **книжной речи** чисто авторская пунктуация не в большом почете и не всем понятна —  вам могут сказать, что **это ошибка и так не бывает** (и уже сказали).

Но при записи **устной речи**, когда интонация важна для говорящего, авторская пунктуация вполне допустима. В то же время надо ясно понимать и уметь объяснить, какие **семантические оттенки она вносит в речь**.

Рассмотрим два варианта, причем оба они "иронические".

— Что за шум? Это у меня убежало молоко?
— НЕт, у менЯ.

— Что за шум? Это у меня убежало молоко?
— Нет у менЯ!

Ирония понятна говорящим в обоих случаях.

Но в **первом варианте** тон спокойный, а ирония более тонкая и выразительная, так что смысл ответа понимается не сразу.

Во **втором** (авторском) варианте без паузы и тире ирония выражена яснее, а тон более эмоциональный и насмешливый.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon. Очень интересно и убедительно!

Comment: Дело в том, что запятые обозначают структуру предложения. Если автор не задумывает паузы вокруг вводного слова, позволяет ли это не ставить запятые?

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что запятая нужна. Здесь "нет" выступает в качестве отрицательной частицы. Теоретически ее даже можно изъять из предложения.

*— Что за шум? Это у меня убежало молоко?

— Нет, у меня!*

Сравните:
— Дай в долг сто рублей.
— Нет у меня!

В этом случае "нет" выступает в качестве сказуемого (смысл: нет у меня денег; нет у меня ста рублей). Изъятие слова невозможно.

Можно еще пофантазировать.

— Это у нас так куры орут?
— Нет, у соседа!

— Сходи к соседу, попроси у него топор.
— Нет у соседа. [= Уже был, уже спрашивал. Нет у соседа топора.]

[**НЕТ**](http://endic.ru/academic/Net-27191.html)

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю, что запятая нужна. По моей версии, "нет" в предложении "нет, у меня" выступает в качестве смыслового эквивалента выражения "у меня". В обоих случаях это завершённый ответ:

> — Что за шум? Это у меня убежало молоко?
>
> — Нет.

Или

> — Что за шум? Это у меня убежало молоко?
>
> — У меня.

В каждом из примеров можно сделать ироничную интонацию.
Значит, если "нет" и "у меня" стоят рядом в одной реплике, их нужно разделять запятой, потому что это не единая фраза.